# ASP.NET Web Pages Bin Deploy Options

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I just deployed my asp.net web pages (.cshtml files) website to a server that doesn't support it (it currently supports webforms and classic asp). It's not executing the .cshtml pages. After researching, I came across [bin deploy](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx) for MVC. Is there something like this for asp.net web pages?

Comment: .cshtml files are views, not intended to be executed directly. What happens when you hit a route to a controller? i.e. `my.url.com/home/index`

Comment: He's not using MVC, merely citing a similar example

Comment: How do you know the server doesn't support it? If it is a web server that is really not SUPPORTING ASP.NET, you can copy as many files as you want - it's not going to run. Check with your provider, please.

Comment: I'm certain that the server supports asp.net (webforms and classic asp), but I can't get .cshtml pages to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install ASP.NET WebPages using [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages/2.0.30506.0) then the required dll's will be deployed in the `bin` folder without having to use the bin deployable hack. NuGet will let you know when they're updated too.

Comment: I'm using VS 2012 and I created a new ASP.NET Web Site (Razor V2) project. I didn't do anything via NuGet. Should I run the linked command then re-deploy?

Comment: I don't have that project template installed in VS so I can't double check myself, can you check if it's added the web pages dll using nuget? (you'll have a packages.config if it has)

Comment: No I don't have a packages.config file. I do have dll's related to web pages in C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies

Comment: OK, remove the references to those dlls and install the nuget package, rebuild and re-deploy and that should solve your problem. The server won't have the `System.Web.WebPages.dll` and other associated bits on it, the nuget package is easier than `bindeployableassemblies`